# Lookup in another, dynamically generated, spreadsheet

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that I need to pull information from another spreadsheet that is automatically generated. The problem with the automatically generated spreadsheet is that the information that I need to pull is not always the same, however the columns that contain the information that I need will always be the same.

I need a formula that looks for a match between a row in my spreadsheet and 'autospreadsheet' when it finds the match, I need it to provide the answer from its corresponding column.

This is nothing like the code, but an example of the basic idea:

If A36 = 'Some value in 'autospreadsheet' column E' -> provide the cell from column I where the match was found.

Would it be best to use a VLOOKUP or a MATCH? Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A36,autospreadsheet!E:I,5,0)
```